# Render ascx control from outside page context

Tags: asp.net

When trying to render the HTML of an ascx UserControl from a WebService, I get the error `RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render`.

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228718/registerforeventvalidation-can-only-be-called-during-render). However the answers given do not work...

The solution always involves `EnableEventValidation="false"` and `override VerifyRenderingInServerForm` but these are only available on a `Page`, not on a `Control` (what the ascx is).

When changing the ascx to an aspx, the following code fails: `page.LoadControl("mycontrol.ascx/aspx")` and rendering an aspx is apparently not so easy according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151155/asp-net-single-control-render-for-ajax-calls).

**The Question**
How can I render my ascx without the exception?

**Bonus question:**
Why is `EnableEventValidation` not available on a Control while there are many examples on the net that claim otherwise? (StackOverflow, CodeProject, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
var page = new System.Web.UI.Page();

// Or RenderControl throws 'RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render'
page.EnableEventValidation = false; 

// Or generates a second hidden field with ID=_VIEWSTATE
page.EnableViewState = false; 
var sb = new StringBuilder();

var ctl = (SomeAscx)page.LoadControl("SomeAscx.ascx");
using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
     ctl.RenderControl(htw);
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Key was setting:

```
page.EnableEventValidation = false; 
page.EnableViewState = false;
```